# Image resize not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-resizing

I am using following code but unable to resize image even `$this->image_lib->resize()` is returning true, don't know what is going wrong:

```
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/avatars/".str_replace('_','-',$image)))
{
    $config['source_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/avatars/".str_replace('_','-',$image);
}   
else if (!file_exists("./uploads/avatars/".$image) || $image=="")
{           
    $config['source_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/avatars/photo.jpg';
}       
else
{           
    $config['source_image'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/avatars/".$image;
}
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';           
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['dynamic_output'] = TRUE;       
$config['width'] = $width;
$config['height'] = $height;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: try using echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();

Comment: Also make sure that your folder and image itself have the right permissions :)

Comment: Yes permissions are also 777, thats why I am wondering what is wrong with this.

Comment: Try using `$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;` and also do a `print_r($config);` to ensure all the options were set as expected.

Comment: Ok I just came to know that this library is actually re-sizing but according to best fit near about my given values and do not re-size physically on disk.

Comment: what the display errors says ?

Comment: @Farhan do you want it to show to the browser and update the file ? I don't think that is possible, dynamic should do one or another. `Determines whether the new image file should be written to disk or generated dynamically.`

Comment: Yeah you are rite @Prix I have manage this by adjusting this dynamically thanks a lot for your kinb help :D

Comment: @Farhan make a answer by clicking on the `Post Your Answer` with how you solved it and mark it as the right answer ;)

Comment: Should I do this tommorw as this is almost my off time from office :p

Answer (score 0):

Try the new_image tag:

```
$config['new_image'] = '/path/to/new_image.jpg';
```

Answer (score -1):

Better to use SimpleImage.php as helper in CodeIgniter

```
$source=base_url().'/uploads/avatars/photo.jpg'; 
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load($source);
$image->resize(600,400);
$image->save($name_and_location);
```